# Runtime error 424 - Object Required error in Outlook VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am running this code in Outlook VBA. It worked fine yesterday, but it is giving this error today. I found my PC rebooted due to some overnight updates when I came into office today. Does that have anything to do with this?

```
Sub test()
    Dim mtd As String

    mydate = Format(Date - 1, "yyyyMMdd")

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim sourceWB

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'error occurs on this line

    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    strFile = "\\disk24\ontime-shared\OTP\Reports\Daily_OTP\" & "Operational_Recap_" & mydate & ".xls"

    Set sourceWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True)
    sourceWB.Worksheets("Summary").Select
    sourceWB.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Cannot see why any updated would remove an `createobject` functionaility. Have you tried rebooting your PC/Outlook?

Comment: yes sir. i tried that. same error message on the same line.

Comment: This is strange. Works fine on mine and worked on yours yesterday. I cannot see why it would occure

Comment: So it works fine on yours? Wow. I am clueless now.

Comment: Yeah copied the code straight from here. Works fine on mine. Only thing I can think of it is to try and put the code in another sub and see if that makes a difference. But I cannot see why it would be failing. Code seems fine to me

Comment: There was a windows update last night. Must have something to do with it, definitely. Thanks for the follow up on you part though!

Comment: Try and find out what update was applied and then see if there is any implications to Outlook. I know there was an update in December 2014 that screwed over ActiveX for a lot of office users. Maybe they have done the same again

Comment: What line of code exactly generates an error?

Comment: Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'error occurs on this line

Comment: I'd check and make sure that Excel is still available for early binding in your references.  Second thing that I'd check after that would be to see if you can use `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` from another VBA application (Word for example).  If neither works, something may have messed up your registry keys.

Comment: Do you have the Click2Run edition of MS Office installed on the PC? Did you try to create a new Excel instance from another application?

Comment: Did you try to use the early binding instead? To use early binding, you first need to reference the available Excel object library. Then you can create an Application instance using the following code: 'Set xl = New Excel.Application'